# Event though registered once, event is fired more than one time

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have defined `$('#userUVEdit-modal').on('click'` event as follows. It has been registered inside another click event. But I do not why it gets fired more than once.

```
$('#usersTable').on('click','.uv-user-edit-btn', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var rowData =   getJqGridRowData($(this).closest('tr'));
    var selectedUserID = $(rowData.userId).find('.uv-user-edit-btn').attr('value');
    var isInstanceAlreadyAssigned = $(rowData.instanceName).attr('id');
    if(isInstanceAlreadyAssigned && typeof isInstanceAlreadyAssigned != undefined) {
        instanceId = isInstanceAlreadyAssigned;
    }else {
        instanceId = -1;
    }

    $('#edit-uv-username').val($(rowData.username).html());

    var requests_interface  =   new requests_interface_instance.getAllInstances();
    requests_interface.init(requests_callback_instance.getAllInstancesCallBack);
    requests_interface.execute();

    // THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION IS FIRED MORE THAN ONCE
    $('#userUVEdit-modal').on('click','#userUVEditButton', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var result = validateRequiredFields('#userUVEdit-modal');
        if(result['status']) {
            var dataObj =   createFormObject('#userUVEdit-modal');
            dataObj['user_id'] = selectedUserID;
            dataObj['instanceId'] = instanceId; // Tells the previous instance allotted
            var requests_interface  =   new requests_interface_instance.mapUserToInstance();
            requests_interface.dataObj = dataObj;
            requests_interface.init(requests_callback_instance.mapUserToInstanceCallBack);
            requests_interface.execute();
        }
    });
});
```

When `#userUVEditButton` is clicked,`$('#userUVEdit-modal').on('click','#userUVEditButton', function(event) {` will be fired but it is fired more than once. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: The reason is that you are binding it again each time `.uv-user-edit-btn` is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because every time you click `.uv-user-edit-btn` you are binding click event on `#userUVEditButton`. Try off() function, which will remove the event handler and then on() will add the event handler on the element.

Example:

```
$('#userUVEdit-modal').off().on('click','#userUVEditButton', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to move the inside click handler, an easy workaround:

```
$('#userUVEdit-modal').off('click').on('click' ...
```